# ServiceStack, Slowness on first Deserialization?

Tags: c#, servicestack, deserialization

I'm testing out alternate Deserialization methods in a C# application. I'm trying out ServiceStack (4.0.38) right now and I'm discovering some odd behavior. Here's my testing code:

```
    public class BasicObject
    {
        public List<string> Stuff { get; set; }

        public BasicObject()
        {
            Stuff = new List<string>();
        }
    }

    private void CustomTesting()
    {
        var largeObject = new BasicObject();
        var mediumObject = new BasicObject();
        var smallObject = new BasicObject();
        //Populate this shiz
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            if (i < 50000)
                mediumObject.Stuff.Add("HelloWorld");

            if (i < 2000)
                smallObject.Stuff.Add("HelloWorld");

            largeObject.Stuff.Add("HelloWorld");
        }

        //Serialize, save to disk
        using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            JsonSerializer.SerializeToStream<BasicObject>(largeObject, stream);
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\Large", stream.ToArray());
        }
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            JsonSerializer.SerializeToStream<BasicObject>(mediumObject, stream);
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\Medium", stream.ToArray());
        }
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            JsonSerializer.SerializeToStream<BasicObject>(smallObject, stream);
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\Small", stream.ToArray());
        }

        var watch = new Stopwatch();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\Large")))
        {
            watch.Start();
            var test = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream<BasicObject>(stream);
            watch.Stop();
        }
        var timeTakenLarge = watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
        watch.Restart();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\Medium")))
        {
            watch.Start();
            var test = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream<BasicObject>(stream);
            watch.Stop();
        }
        var timeTakenMedium = watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
        watch.Restart();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\Small")))
        {
            watch.Start();
            var test = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream<BasicObject>(stream);
            watch.Stop();
        }
        var timeTakenSmall = watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
        watch.Restart();

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  {1}  {2}", timeTakenLarge, timeTakenMedium, timeTakenSmall));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Pretty simple, take a basic object, populate it with 3 different ranges of data. Serialize it, save it to disk. Then later take the saved file in a memory stream and see how long it takes ServiceStack to deserialize. Here's my output (times in milliseconds)

```
Deserialization Order: Large Med Small
Display Order: Large Med Small
209  61  1
222  73  1
178  57  1
174  60  1

Deserialization Order: Small Med Large
Display Order: Large Med Small
145  48  66
128  72  63   
100  58  79
98  55  57

Deserialization Order: Med Small Large
Display Order: Large Med Small
106  130  1
155  114  1
106  199  1
115  217  1
```

For some reason Which ever deserialization occurs first will be a bit slow. Why is this? Is ServiceStack maybe caching info about the object behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most serializers are optimized for run-time performance where the first iteration will be slow due to creating and compiling all the required delegates containing optimal code-paths which are then cached and re-used for subsequent serialization of the cached types.